# Find Key in Python Dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

```
ls = ['app.js', 'app.srt']
d = {
    'name':('.srt','.mp3'),
    'age':('uzair','.js')
}
def find_key(ls,d):
    for item in ls:
        for key,value in d.items():
            for val in value:
                if val == item:
                    return key
```

I am tried to find a key from this program but i don't know how to do it....please help!!

Comment: Try list(d.keys()) which returns a list of dictionary keys.

Comment: How does `ls` related to `d`? None of the items in `ls` are in the dict, either as keys or values.

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? Like what output are you trying to get? Please [edit] to clarify. BTW welcome to SO! Check out [ask] if you want advice.

Answer (score 1):

```
def find_key(ls,d):
    for item in ls:
        if item in d:
            return item
```

I have doubt that you want to do something else

Answer (score 1):

You're comparison is faulty. Instead of `==`, the appropriate operation in this case would be `in`.

```
def find_key(files, extensions):
    res = []
    for file in files:
        for key, extension in extensions.items():
            for ext in extension:
                if ext in file:
                    res.append(key)
    return res


if __name__ == '__main__':
    files = ['app.js', 'app.srt']
    extension_dict = {
        'name': ('.srt', '.mp3'),
        'age': ('uzair', '.js')
    }

    print(find_key(files, extension_dict))
```

The output:

```
['age', 'name']
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the method `keys()` of the dictionary object.

Here you have some examples:
https://developers.google.com/edu/python/dict-files

Answer (score 0):

Based on your given info, here is the sol.

```
ls = ['app.js', 'app.srt']
d = {
    'name':('.srt','.mp3'),
    'age':('uzair','.js')
}
def find_key(ls,d):
    keys=[]
    for item in ls:
        for key,value in d.items():
                if '.'+item.split('.')[1] in value:
                    keys.append( (key, item))
    return keys

print(find_key(ls,d))
```

output:

```
[('age', 'app.js'), ('name', 'app.srt')]
```

Answer (score 0):

actually == operator will look for exactly what is on the left side in the right side of operator.
So for ur case you want to match substring. Use **in** operator instead of **==**